# Is there a default alert in iOS similar to the personal hotspot notification?

Tags: ios, alert

Is there a default alert in iOS like the personal hotspot notification?

Example:

[image: Personal hotspot notification]

Comment: The only built-in alert I know of is UIAlertView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hotspot connection notification is a special mode of the status bar (same for the in-call status bar, and audio recording status bar). There is no publicly available API for doing this with your own notifications.